# How should I go about stopping/resuming all sounds within my iOS game?

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I currently have background music that starts up when the app opens and runs an infinite loop until the user goes into the settings and turns the music off using this

```
-(IBAction)stopMusicButton{

[(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate stopMusic];



}
```

They can also resume the music in the settings page. What I'm a confused about is how to stop the other sounds in my app from playing if the user doesn't want the noise. For example, when the user navigates the menu of my app there are various sounds that play when certain things are pressed. How can I allow the user to be able to toggle these sounds on and off? There are also a few different views with their respective .h/.m files, all of which play sounds. If you could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a singleton class to store settings information - you could probably use your app delegate as well. All you need is a boolean property called isSoundMuted or something like that. Set that whenever the sound is muted or unmuted, then check the variable's value before playing any sounds in an if block.

```
if (MySingletonClass.isSoundMuted == NO)
{
    [self playSound]
}
```